# Why might my ceiling light be flickering?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, united-kingdom

I have two lights in my bedroom on the same circuit with a single switch. One of them (always the same one) will sometimes flicker to the point that it's strobing. It doesn't do it all of the time, and there doesn't seem to be a correlation between it doing it and how log it's been switched on (sometimes it does it straight away, sometimes it can be on for ages and not do it). I am assuming there's no issue with the supply or fuses or I'd be seeing it on both light fittings.

I've tried a different bulb. The bedroom is in an extension that is about 5 years old so the wiring should be fairly up to code and in good condition. I can't access the wiring above it as the attic is boarded and insulated, but nothing should be disturbing it if, for example, there was a loose connection.

There is nothing obviously (to me) wrong with the wiring.

Switch wiring:
[image]

Good light wiring:
[image]

Problem light wiring:
[image]

Comment: That's not by chance a dimmer switch, is it?

Comment: I would turn off the breaker and check the connections in both lights just to be sure a loose connection is not the problem.  Changing the bulb should have checked that it was not a bad light bulb.  Type of light bulb can be useful, LEDs seem to have more flickering problems.

Comment: @Huesmann No, not a dimmer.

Comment: @crip659 The one with the problem is an LED bulb, the other one is an older sytle mercury low-energy bulb. How am I checking for loose connections? Just giving things a pull and tightening them up?

Answer (score 1):

Low quality LED bulbs have an irritating tendency to flicker on occasion and sometimes constantly.

While I know of no scientific study to support this, I can tell you from experience that when faced with a the flickering bulb, I have replaced it with a bulb from one of the better reviewed companies.

(One review post is [here](https://bestreviews.com/home/light-bulbs/best-led-light-bulbs?cid=198434321&aid=52873694315&eid=&tid=kwd-324166162274&ul=9052080&mt=e&n=g&d=c&dm=&dt&sn&adid=546662821649&k=best%20led%20light%20bulbs&p=&pc=&ap=).)

A better bulb has historically given me better service.

Comment: Other bulbs from the same batch are all working fine. When I get some time, I'll try to do a more scientific test and swap some around.

Comment: Understand that not every bulb from a batch may flicker.  It is not uncommon for a bulb to be fine then develop a flicker and even have a flicker that goes away ( If one is willing to put up with it long enough.)

Answer (score -1):

The flicker is very unlikely to be related to any wiring.

LEDs don't do well in fully enclosed lamps because they trap heat and make the bulb's complex electronics run hot. Whereas incandescent bulb's simple metal and glass combo don't care about a 30C increase in operating temp caused by lack of ventilation in the lamp housing.

If you must keep that fixture, find an LED bulb line with the highest lumen-to-watt ratio you can find, and then use the lowest wattage you can stand, both of which are efforts to avoid heat, which is what causes internal driver failure (the most common fail method and synonymous with flickering/strobing) and lower-life LED chips.

Larger watt LED bulbs are usually physically larger and have more surface area to dissipate heat, so long is it's not all trapped by the fixture; like a globe for example. Putting such a lamp fixture behind a dimmer, using a larger-watt bulb, and then running it at 50-75% is a good way to run the bulb cooler, reduce flicker, increase efficiency (albeit slightly), and ensure long lifespan.

Comment: Thanks. The lamp shades are pretty open so I'm not sure it's a heat issue. Will try to post a picture.